# turtle.textinput() is not working in one of my codes but it works in the other

Tags: python

I am currently working on a game in python using the `turtle` library import. Before I add anything to the main game always test it in another python file to make sure it works.

I came across the `turtle.textinput()`

It worked in my test code but not in my actual game. When I tried to put it in the actual game it says

```
AttributeError: type object 'Turtle' has no attribute textinput
```

This makes no sense. I use VS code so I don't understand what is going on please help

P.S. : I couldn't figure out the code highlight thing so I put it in brackets.

Comment: In the non-working case, you have apparently done something like `turtle = Turtle`.

Answer (score 1):

textinput() is a method in Screen class

Answer (score 0):

Note that `textinput()` is a method in the `Screen` instance, and not in the turtle.

```py
from turtle import Screen

screen = Screen()

screen.textinput("Title Example", "Prompt example")
```